# Buttons on UITableViewCell not working when in editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a `UITableView` populated with cells that have buttons on them. I want those buttons to work also when in editing mode, but they don't. It seems like the gesture recognizer on `UITableViewCell` is preventing gesture recognizers on buttons. Does anyone have any suggestions about approaching this problem?

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.items = [@[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four"] mutableCopy];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"cellID" 
                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    [cell.button setTitle: self.items[indexPath.row] 
                 forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    return cell;
}

 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return YES;
 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.items removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

TableViewCell.h:

```
@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

So, the `buttonTapped:` is called when a cell isn't in editing mode, but when a cell is in editing mode, the button doesn't work.

Comment: You may want to show the code you use for, 1- how button are added, 2- how you enable the "editing" mode, 3- any gesture recognizer you used.

Comment: I was referring to UIKit's usage of gestureRecognizers. Button is added in storyboard

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do this, you need to subclass the UITableView and make it conform to a UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol. In .m file of your UITableView subclass add the following code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different tags from each button in the cells. For example,

Inside **cellforRowAtIndexPath**, specify a tag for a button.

```
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(func:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[Button setTag:indexPath.row];
```

Now call the function and refer the cell using tag.

```
-(IBAction)func:(id)sender event:(id)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint Pos = [touch locationInView:self.tableview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:Pos];
    if(indexPath != nil){
        //do operation with indexPath
    }
 }
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

First of all see some code what you have done !! without proper declaration its difficult to give answer.
Firstly My suggestion is give gesture recognize in UItableview delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// code

}
```

Sometimes gesture is not working with small mistake in coding.

Secondly if possible ,

Instead of adding the Gesture recognizer to the Cell directly, you can add it to the UItableview in viewDidLoad.
This is the best way to work gesture in UITableview.

As said by [**Phix**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550177/phix23) in Example,

In the didSwipe-Method you can determine the affected IndexPath and cell as follows:

```
-(void)didSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

  if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint swipeLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
        UITableViewCell* swipedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
        // ...
  }
}
```

You can set other gesture like as Above.
I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't formulated good. I updated it, so check if you see any solutions now. Thanks for your help anyways